# Imagelist view with BaseAdapter

Tags: android, android-listview, android-imageview, baseadapter, universal-image-loader

I have not done much java and android and got stuck in loading an image into a listview. Hopefully I'm on the right track of something by using a BaseAdapter. Now I am trying only one image, but eventually it will be a list of images. Tried following some tutorials but no luck.

I am using Andorid-Universal-Image-Downloader(https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader) to download the images. Permission for internet and storage is added. Still there is nothing happening, just a blank screen, here is my code:

ImageAdapter:

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private final Context context;
ImageLoader imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
Bitmap image;


public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
    this.context = c;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, parent, false);
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.imageView);

    imageLoader.init(ImageLoaderConfiguration.createDefault(context));

    imageLoader.loadImage("urlToImage", new SimpleImageLoadingListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLoadingComplete(String imageUri, View view, Bitmap loadedImage) {
            image = loadedImage;
        }
    });
    imageView.setImageBitmap(image);    

    return row;

}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}

}
```

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

ListView listView;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

    ImageAdapter adapter = new ImageAdapter(this);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

}
}
```

xml:

```
----main.xml----
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<ListView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/listView" />
</LinearLayout>    



----row.xml----
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:minHeight="64dp">

<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="9dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: have you provided the urlToImage in getView()?

Comment: Yes, double checked it now and tested the url in browser.

Comment: have a look here you can replace the gallery by a listview when you have your adapter done http://learnandroideasily.blogspot.com/2013/07/android-gallery-view-example.html

Answer (score 0):

Your `getCount` returns 0, so the ListView is not requesting any views from the adapter. Try returning 1 - might help.